# Datagridview to excel - Vertical

Tags: excel, vb.net, datagridview

I need help with the following exporting. I have form 1 with the following;

```
Public Class Form1
Dim table As New DataTable("table")
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim dgvTextColumn As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    DataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill
    DataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height = 120
    DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = True
    table.Columns.Add("Forename", Type.GetType("System.String"))
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    table.Rows.Add(TextBox1.Text)
    DataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill
    DataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height = 120
    DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = False
    DataGridView1.DataSource = table
    Me.Hide()
    Form2.Show()
End Sub
```

Upon entering a forename into textbox1, the user would select button3 which would load form2. In form2 i have the following code;

```
Public Class Form2
Dim table As New DataTable("table")
Dim ds As DataSet = Nothing
Dim dt As DataTable = Nothing

Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ds = New DataSet()
    dt = New DataTable()

    ds.Tables.Add(dt)

    Dim my_DataView As DataView = ds.Tables(0).DefaultView
    Me.Datagridview1.DataSource = my_DataView
    Dim dgvTextColumn As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    Datagridview1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill
    Datagridview1.RowTemplate.Height = 120
    Datagridview1.AllowUserToAddRows = True
    table.Columns.Add("Forename", Type.GetType("System.String"))
End Sub

Public Function FlipDataSet(my_DataSet As DataSet) As DataSet
    Dim ds As New DataSet()

    For Each dt As DataTable In my_DataSet.Tables
        Dim table As New DataTable()

        For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count
            table.Columns.Add(Convert.ToString(i))
        Next
        Dim r As DataRow
        For k As Integer = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
            r = table.NewRow()
            r(0) = dt.Columns(k).ToString()
            For j As Integer = 1 To dt.Rows.Count
                r(j) = dt.Rows(j - 1)(k)
            Next
            table.Rows.Add(r)
        Next

        ds.Tables.Add(table)
    Next

    Return ds
End Function

Private Sub butNormal_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButNormal.Click
    Dim datagridview1 As DataView = ds.Tables(0).DefaultView
    Me.Datagridview1.DataSource = datagridview1

    Butflip.Enabled = True
    ButNormal.Enabled = False
End Sub

Private Sub butFlip_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Butflip.Click
    Dim new_ds As DataSet = FlipDataSet(ds)
    ' Flip the DataSet
    Dim my_DataView As DataView = new_ds.Tables(0).DefaultView
    Me.Datagridview1.DataSource = my_DataView

    Butflip.Enabled = False
    ButNormal.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim new_ds As DataSet = FlipDataSet(ds)
    ' Flip the DataSet
    Dim my_DataView As DataView = new_ds.Tables(0).DefaultView
    Me.Datagridview1.DataSource = my_DataView

    Butflip.Enabled = False
    ButNormal.Enabled = True

    Butflip.Enabled = False
    ButNormal.Enabled = True
    Datagridview1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill
    Datagridview1.RowTemplate.Height = 120
    Datagridview1.AllowUserToAddRows = False
    Datagridview1.DataSource = table

    table.Rows.Add(Form1.TextBox1.Text)

    'Save to excel with headers
    Dim ExcelApp As Object, ExcelBook As Object
    Dim ExcelSheet As Object
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim Proceed As Boolean = False




    'create object of exce
    ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    ExcelBook = ExcelApp.WorkBooks.Add
    ExcelSheet = ExcelBook.WorkSheets(1)

    With ExcelSheet
        For Each column As DataGridViewColumn In Datagridview1.Columns
            .cells(1, column.Index + 1) = column.HeaderText
        Next
        For i = 1 To Me.Datagridview1.RowCount
            .cells(i + 1, 1) = Me.Datagridview1.Rows(i - 1).Cells("Forename").Value
            For j = 1 To Datagridview1.Columns.Count - 1
                .cells(i + 1, j + 1) = Datagridview1.Rows(i - 1).Cells(j).Value
            Next
            Dim formatRange As Excel.Range
            formatRange = ExcelSheet.Range("a1")
            formatRange.EntireRow.Font.Bold = True
            formatRange = ExcelSheet.Range("A1", "V1")
            formatRange.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.LightBlue)
            formatRange.BorderAround(Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous)
            formatRange = ExcelSheet.Range("a1", "V1")
            formatRange.EntireRow.BorderAround()
        Next
    End With

    ExcelApp.Visible = True
    '
    ExcelSheet = Nothing
    ExcelBook = Nothing
    ExcelApp = Nothing

    Application.Exit()
    End
End Sub
```

When clicking button1 it exports the data in datagridview along with the header 'Forename' and the data inserted into form1.textbox1.text underneith but it should change to vertical. This isn't happened and i don't know where i'm going wrong.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where is the question? // https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Question has been improved

Comment: Anyone help!? This is driving me insane

Comment: Please read the How-To I linked. You don't want to start a question with your code. Try to explain your situation and what's not working and what it is supposed to do before you post your code. Also try to reduce the linked code to a minimum. See [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for that.

Comment: @Luke thanks for the response. My problem is at this moment is the header still remains in row 1 rather than row 2 and the data inserted into textbox1 is still showing under the header rather than beside.

Comment: [My Project](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArAq6tP9fO2jiEeezQ-TltzF_kHn) Here is a copy of my project. I've managed to get the data inserted into textbox1 to populate once clicking flip or normal button, but it overwrites the header 'Forename' Do you know how i could overcome this issue?